# ns typings command error "parse error near `\n'"

Tags: kotlin, nativescript, typescript-typings, aar

I have a really small kotlin library to test how to import it into nativescript.
I've fallen down at the step when creating typings for ns. I'm getting always the same error:
`zsh: parse error near` \n'`

The steps I did for now...

The kotlin class:

```
package com.example.mytestlibrary

class MyFirst {
    fun getMySentence(): String {
        return "Lorem Ipsum"
    }
}
```

I've built an .aar from the lib in Android Studio and unziped to access the jar file and put the files into NS project.

If I run `ns typings android –-jar <./libs/MyTestLibrary/classes.jar>`
I get this error: **zsh: parse error near `\n'**

I can't find out why?

Answer (score 0):

Also stuck in this step. But I got workaround this.

```
ns typings android --jar .
```

Run above command in root of project then you will get all the needed data.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34677761)